# I am trying to create a rect element within a svg element, but its not working

Tags: javascript, html, svg, rect

Why is the red rectangle not appearing when I run the function `createRect()`. Any help would be much appreciated.

```js
function createRect() {
    var rec = document.createElement("rect");
    rec.style.width = "100px";
    rec.style.height = "100px";
    rec.style.left = "0px";
    rec.style.top = "0px";
    rec.style.fill = "red";
    rec.style.position = "absolute";
    var elem = document.getElementById("container");
    elem.append(rec);


}

window.onload = createRect;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Tetris(test)</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styleSheets/main.css">
    <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
    <script src = "js/jquery.1.js"></script>
    <script src = "js/main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <svg id="container" width= "500" height= "650" style= "background-color: black" position= "relative">
      </svg>

  </body>
</html>
```

After I run this function onload, a red box should appear in the upper left corner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe so

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Tetris(test)</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styleSheets/main.css">
    <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
    <script src = "js/jquery.1.js"></script>
    <script src = "js/main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <svg id="container" width= "500" height= "650" style= "background-color: black">
      </svg>

  </body>
</html>

<script>
function createRect() {
const svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
const svg = document.querySelector("svg");
const rec = document.createElementNS(svgNS ,'rect');
 rec.setAttribute('width', 100);
 rec.setAttribute('height', 100);
 rec.setAttribute('x', 50);
 rec.setAttribute('y', 50);
 rec.setAttribute('fill', 'red');
  
 svg.appendChild(rec);
}

window.onload = createRect;


</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function createRect() {
    var rec = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg',"rect");
    rec.style.width = "100px";
    rec.style.height = "100px";
    rec.style.left = "0px";
    rec.style.top = "0px";
    rec.style.fill = "red";
    rec.style.position = "relative";
    var elem = document.getElementById("container");
    elem.append(rec);
}
```

Comment: what does this do?

Comment: it means you are creating svg element not html

Comment: it just name space for svg

Comment: is it the link to my html file?

Comment: go to this page:- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElementNS

Comment: use rect.x = 50; rect.y=50; not rect.style.top and left