# svg append child element not render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Following is my code, I expect append rect to (I wanna dynamic add rect with js not put in component#render), but rect is not shown

```
       var rect: any = document.createElement("rect")
        rect.setAttribute("x", 0)
        rect.setAttribute("y", 0)
        rect.setAttribute("width", 200)
        rect.setAttribute("height", 100)
        rect.setAttribute("fill", "black")

        var svg: SVGSVGElement
        act(() => {
            ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#root")).render(<svg ref={e => svg = e}></svg>)
        })
        svg.appendChild(rect)
```

Comment: "I wanna dynamic add rect with js not put in component#render" - why?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it's react builtin test-utils #act

Comment: Separately, I *think* that `createElement` call is incorrect. Shouldn't it be using [`createElementNS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElementNS)? `document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg',"rect")` See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59297617/i-am-trying-to-create-a-rect-element-within-a-svg-element-but-its-not-working

Comment: @casraf just confused, why does js append element not render

Comment: Just checked your code (without React, just with an SVG already in a document) and the rectangle didn't appear. It does appear if I fix the `createElement` call, so I think that's the problem.

Comment: Seems to me you might want to try using `appendChild` inside the `ref` callback, not sure if that'll work, but putting it outside like that definitely doesn't work - `act` seems to have async code in it, which means the line after it will run before its code is actually run - which is why the svg is not appending. Also - you are not appending the rect to the svg at any point, so even if the svg appears properly (it's not clear if it does from your question), the rect would not be appended anywhere in it

Comment: @casraf - I wondered about asynchronicity too, but [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/testing-recipes.html#act) suggests that `act` is not asynchronous. I think the reason it accepts a callback is it needs to do some plumbing before doing the work (and possibly after).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I see, thank you. But what about the `ref` callback? Does the `svg` actually get assigned properly?

Comment: @casraf - I'm afraid I don't know, but I would expect so. It's a testing facility, and testing a ref seems like something you'd want to do. :-)

Comment: @chikadance - FWIW, this slightly modified version using `createElementNS` works for me: https://pastebin.com/ST9KrR7K I couldn't seem to get `act` to call its callback, so I just used the testing stuff set up by create-react-app (so lazy! :-) ). So the environment isn't an exact match, but...